# How to set battery threshold options in Ubuntu 18.04LTS (Dell inspiron 13 Model)

Tags: ubuntu

*I'm little bit workaholic, I often forgot to unplug my laptop battery charger after It was 100% charge. How do I setup the battery charging threshold option for DELL Inspiron 13 (1538) model using Ubuntu. I searched in web, I didn't get clear cut information using TLP. (Battery threshold options are only applicable to Lenovo ThinkPad laptops) Suggestions!*